# Request Adapter Interceptor Same thing in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I am try to change request before and After response call of AfNetworking. I have done in Alamofire using Request Adapter. Can any one help me same thing on AFNetworking.

Below link which explains clearly to for Alamofire 3 and 4
https://grokswift.com/custom-headers-alamofire4-swift3/